# How to Convert BGRA buffer to RGBA buffer format?

Tags: c++, video-streaming, rgba

How can i Convert BGRA buffer to RGBA buffer format in C++

```
void ConvertBetweenBGRAandRGBA(unsigned char* input, int pixel_width,int pixel_hight,
                           unsigned char* output) {

        for (int y = 0; y < pixel_hight; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < pixel_width; x++) {
        const unsigned char* pixel_in = &input[y * x * 4];

        unsigned char* pixel_out = &output[y * x * 4];
        pixel_out[0] = pixel_in[2];
        pixel_out[1] = pixel_in[1];
        pixel_out[2] = pixel_in[0];
        pixel_out[3] = pixel_in[3];
     }
}
```

but i am not getting background color.

pls any one help me?

Comment: If you are not getting the background color then what are you getting exactly?  Give an example value in and the value out your getting.  Have you verified your for loop is even doing what you want?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't C#, so please re-tag it appropriately.

Assuming this is bitmap data, firstly, you need to figure out the *stride* of the image. The stride is the number of bytes that each row of pixels uses. This is not always equal to `bytes_per_pixel * pixels_per_row`. It's usually aligned to four bytes, so in this case (since ARGB pixels use four bytes per pixel) you should be OK.

Secondly, your formula for getting the address of pixel (x, y) is wrong. Pixels are stored in row-major order. This means that, starting from offset 0 in the pixel buffer, you will see one complete row of pixel data; and then another complete row; and so on. There's a full stride of bytes for every row of pixel data.

You *could* do this:

```
const unsigned char* pixel_in = &input[((y * pixel_width) + x) * 4];
```

But if your stride is indeed equal to the image width, you don't need to calculate the address each time because the pixels will be stored sequentially:

```
void ConvertBetweenBGRAandRGBA(unsigned char* input, int pixel_width,
    int pixel_height, unsigned char* output)
{
    int offset = 0;

    for (int y = 0; y < pixel_height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < pixel_width; x++) {
            output[offset] = input[offset + 2];
            output[offset + 1] = input[offset + 1];
            output[offset + 2] = input[offset];
            output[offset + 3] = input[offset + 3];

            offset += 4;
        }
    }
}
```

If it still doesn't show up right, then confirm what the correct pixel packing is. It should either be ARGB or BGRA; I've never heard of pixels packed as RGBA.

Answer (score 0):

Jeff's awnser works but there is a little detail you never store the the 1st offset.
just add a temp value and it will work like a charm like it did for me :D

```
void ConvertBetweenBGRAandRGBA(unsigned char* input, int pixel_width, int pixel_height, unsigned char* output)
{
    int offset = 0;

    for (int y = 0; y < pixel_height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < pixel_width; x++) {

            auto temp = output[offset];
            output[offset] = input[offset + 2];
            output[offset + 1] = input[offset + 1];
            output[offset + 2] = temp;
            output[offset + 3] = input[offset + 3];

            offset += 4;
        }
    }
}
```